# CoffeeScript scope issue

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

What am I doing wrong here? I'm using the fat arrows => for my callbacks, however when the code reaches cb.onEndElement and calls @returner I get an null object exception.  So why doesn't @returner exist?

```coffee
class Parser
    constructor: () ->
        @returner = (data) ->

    searchParser: new xml.SaxParser (cb) =>
        cb.onStartElementNS (elem, attrs, prefix, url, ns) =>
            if elem is "results" then @results = []
            else if elem is "title" then @curr = "title"
            else @curr = "none"
        cb.onCdata (cdata) =>
            if @curr is "title" then @book.title = cdata
        cb.onEndElementNS (elem, prefix, url) =>
            @results.push @book if elem is "book"
        cb.onEndDocument =>
            @returner @results

    search: (str, callback) ->
        @returner = callback
        @searchParser.parseString str

p = new Parser
p.search "somexml", (data) ->
    console.log JSON.stringify data
```

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method `search` needs a fat-arrow `=>` in order to bind it to instances of `Parser`.

Additionally, although the line `searchParser: new xml.SaxParser (cb) =>` compiles, it's probably not doing what you want, because the fat arrow is binding the callback to `Parser` and not `this`. You have two options:

1. you should probably put `@searchParser = new xml.SaxParser (cb) => ...` in your constructor instead, given the way you are calling it.
2. otherwise you could use `searchParser: () => new xml.SaxParser (cb) =>` and call it with parens lower down: `@searchParser().parseString str`, which would create a `searchParser` method bound to `this`

As an example, here are my two solutions, as well as your original line, slightly simplified, as well as the compiled code, for compare and contrast purposes:

Simplified example in CoffeeScript:

```
class Parser
  constructor: () -> @searchParser1 = new xml.SaxParser (x) => console.log(x)
  searchParser2: () => new xml.SaxParser (x) => console.log(x)
  searchParser: new xml.SaxParser (x) => console.log(x)
```

Compiled JavaScript:

```
var Parser;
var __bind = function(fn, me){ return function(){ return fn.apply(me, arguments); }; };
Parser = (function() {
  function Parser() {
    this.searchParser2 = __bind(this.searchParser2, this);    
    this.searchParser1 = new xml.SaxParser(__bind(function(x) {
      return console.log(x);
    }, this));
  }
  Parser.prototype.searchParser2 = function() {
    return new xml.SaxParser(__bind(function(x) {
      return console.log(x);
    }, this));
  };
  Parser.prototype.searchParser = new xml.SaxParser(__bind(function(x) {
    return console.log(x);
  }, Parser));
  return Parser;
}).call(this);
```

Note how `searchParser1` and `searchParser2` have their callbacks bound to `this` and `searchParser`'s is bound to `Parser`.

As always, the "Try CoffeeScript" button at the CoffeeScript homepage (http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/) is your friend!

Answer (score 3):

First off, the concept you're talking about isn't "scope"—it's `this`, also informally called the "context." And it's certainly one of the trickiest concepts in JavaScript (and thus CoffeeScript), even though the rules are fairly simple. Perhaps it's because the word `this` itself, which doesn't seem like its meaning should be so easily changed depending on how a function is called...

Nicholas' answer is dead-on, but I recommend that you also read up on `this` and try to really understand it, rather than just using `=>` all the time (it's a great tool, but not always the right one). A few resources I recommend:

- JavaScript Garden's [section on `this`](http://javascriptgarden.info/#function.this)
- How to Node's article [What is `this`?](http://howtonode.org/what-is-this)
- My book, [CoffeeScript: Accelerated JavaScript Development](http://pragprog.com/titles/tbcoffee/coffeescript) (a shameless plug, yes, but it does explain `this`, as well as scope, in a fair amount of depth)