# Meteor.Stream scoping issues

Tags: javascript, meteor, coffeescript

On the server-side I have

```
class Service
  constructor: (@options = {}) ->
    @guiStream = new Meteor.Stream('gui')
    @guiStream.on('toggle', ->
      console.log "Toggle event handler called OK."
      @toggle()
    )

  toggle: (_activate) ->
    @activated = if not _activate? then not @activated else _activate
```

I want to invoke the toggle method in Service after the 'toggle' event is emitted from a template on the client. The event handling works OK, but how can I invoke the toggle method of Service from inside of the event handler? Since @ is in the scope of @guiStream and not Service, the above yields

```
Exception while invoking method 'stream-gui' ReferenceError: toggle is not defined
```

Any idea how I could do this properly? The toggle method contains a lot more that I have removed here for brevity. It's used throughout Service, so I would rather not put it inside of @guiStream if that's avoidable.

Comment: Even more bizarre considering an [this](https://github.com/arunoda/streams-blackboard/blob/master/lib/remote_user.js) in an example app for Meteor.Stream, where positionPointer is called from an event handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `@guiStream.on('toggle', ->` to use fat arrow `=>`, it works. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038845/coffeescript-scope-issue?rq=1) related topic.